# Summing linq data by year

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I've seen dozens of posts similar to this, but I just can't get it to work.

Using asp.net MVC framework, I have a table named Contributions that contains a "ContributionDate" column and an "Amount" column. I'm loading the dates and amounts to display in a chart:

```
var results = db.Contributions.Where(c => c.Amount > 0);

ArrayList xValue = new ArrayList();
ArrayList yValue = new ArrayList();

results.ToList().ForEach(c => xValue.Add(c.ContributionDate));
results.ToList().ForEach(c => yValue.Add(c.Amount));
```

The above works. Now I'd liked to sum (i.e., total) the Amounts for each year. I've seen examples that are similar to the following, but I'm clearly clueless (in this example, the compiler doesn't like the "c.ContributionDate" in the new{} statement):

```
var results = db.Contributions
.Where(c => c.Amount > 0)
.GroupBy( c => c.ContributionDate )
.Select(c => new {Amount = c.Sum(b => b.Amount), Date=c.ContributionDate});
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should consider using the generic `List<T>` class instead of the obsoleted `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you perform a `GroupBy`, the key by which you're grouping elements is represented by the [`Key`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx) property.

Try this:

```
var results = db.Contributions
    .Where(c => c.Amount > 0)
    .GroupBy( c => c.ContributionDate )
    .Select(c => new { Amount = c.Sum(b => b.Amount), Date = c.Key });
```

But this will group items by the entire `ContributionDate` value, not just by the year. To do that, you'd have to do something like this:

```
var results = db.Contributions
    .Where(c => c.Amount > 0)
    .GroupBy( c => c.ContributionDate.Year)
    .Select(c => new 
    { 
        Amount = c.Sum(b => b.Amount), 
        Date = new DateTime(c.Key, 1, 1) 
    });
```

But since this appears to be Entity Framework, you probably need to use the [`CreateDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.createdatetime) function:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

...

var results = db.Contributions
    .Where(c => c.Amount > 0)
    .GroupBy( c => c.ContributionDate.Year)
    .Select(c => new 
    { 
        Amount = c.Sum(b => b.Amount), 
        Date = EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime(c.Key, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) 
    });
```

Comment: Wow! Fantastic. Thanks. I spent so many newbie hours on this. FWIW, the second example caused a "Only parameterless constructors are supported in LINQ to Entities" error, but I simply added ".Year" to the ContributionDate in your first example and it worked. Thank you, thank you.

Comment: @SteveA If you're query works as is, I assume `ContributionDate` is already only has the year part, and I'd go with the first solution. But see my updated answer for a solution that works in Linq-to-Entities.

Comment: Thanks pswg. Your first query worked, but since the ContributionDate is a DateTime, I needed to add the .Year (as mentioned in my first comment). Works great.